# Framework not found in firebase sdk

Tags: objective-c

I have tried to add firebase sdk using pods, but when I run the project I am getting the error framework not found. What can I do to solve this issue?

[image: error]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots. Include the relevant errors as text in your question.

Comment: I edited to include the screenshot in the comment, but *please* always post error codes as text. Same goes with code. Posting images lets people see your code or errors, but not interact with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually add a framework. Follow below steps:

1) Click on your project top left side.

2) Open Build Phase.

3) Open Link Binary with Libraries.

4) Add your framework and run your project.

I had the same issue. Its resolved once I added it.